# Qual è il significato di "lisciata" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia del nuovo cognome* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> A parenti e amici aveva detto che era caduta sugli scogli di Amalfi in una bella mattinata di sole, quando lei e il marito erano andati in barca fino a una spiaggia proprio sotto una parete gialla. Durante il pranzo per il fidanzamento di suo fratello e Pinuccia aveva usato, nel dire quella bugia, un tono ironico e tutti le avevano ironicamente creduto, specialmente le femmine, che sapevano da sempre cosa bisognava dire quando i maschi che volevano loro bene e a cui volevano bene picchiavano sodo. Per di più non c’era persona del rione, specialmente di sesso femminile, che non pensasse che lei avesse bisogno da tempo di una bella **lisciata**. Perciò le botte non avevano fatto scandalo e anzi intorno a Stefano erano cresciuti simpatia e rispetto, ecco uno che sapeva fare l’uomo.

Ho cercato il significato di "lisciata" in alcuni dizionari. Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/lisciata/), per esempio, ho trovato

> s. f. [der. di *lisciare*]. – L’atto del lisciare una volta sola o rapidamente, alla lesta: *dare una l. all’asse con la pialla*; *si diede una l. ai capelli e uscì di corsa*. ◆ Dim. **lisciatina**, soprattutto in senso fig., adulazione, lusinga: *tutte queste lisciatine mirano a qualche cosa!*

Le definizioni che ho trovato in altri dizionari sono simili, ma non sembrano avere molto senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire "lisciata" nel brano sopra citato?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/lisciare/), *lisciare* significato 1a

> *un liscio e busso* (o liscebusso), una bastonatura, o una strapazzata (v. liscebusso)

*Liscio e busso* sembra un uso meridionale (almeno secondo il vocabolario), ma in generale ho sentito altre volte *lisciare la schiena* e *accarezzare la schiena* come eufemismo per indicare bastonare o picchiare.